# Проброс session из Node.js в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, node.js, express

Есть:

- WordPress по адресу`example.domain`
- Node.js Express с Passport.js по адресу `example.domain/node`

Node.js хранит `connect.sid` в cookies

На стороне сервера в Node REST API я могу проверить авторизацию юзера через `res.isAuthenticated` когда юзер обращается к API

Но как проверить это через WordPress?

В данном случае WP представляет собой MVC клиент, который генерит представления

Node.js работает чисто как отдельный REST API 
Но крутится это всё на одном домене

Есть несколько идей:

- Создать метод на стороне Node.js и ко всем элементам в WP page привязать какой-нибудь class/id типа "isAuth" и при загрузке страницы пинается созданный метод на стороне Node.js и если метод возвращает 401, то дропать эти теги
- Переместить WP целиком под обработку Node.js, т.е. всякий раз когда идёт обращение к корню WP оно сначала обрабатывается Node.js
- Каким-то магическим образом парсить куки/localstorage через WP (investigation поставил меня в тупик)

Задача заключается в том, что мы можем на этапе подготовки страницы WP понимать, что юзер авторизован

Идей много, какое направление будет лучшее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как WP и Node.js имеют общий домен, то Cookies они хранят в одном месте

В WP Вы можете получить Cookies через $_COOKIE["ИМЯ КУКИ"]

Passport.js из Node.js хранит session_id как cookies с именем connect_sid

Следовательно, при обращении к любой странице WP, мы можем получить в cookies connect_sid и провалидировать его на стороне Node.js подменив сессию

Node (создаём отдельный роут):

```js
router.get("/check", function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.isAuthenticated)
})
```

WP:

```php
function get_auth_state(){
    $cookie = 'Cookie: connect.sid=' . urlencode($_COOKIE["connect_sid"]) . ';';

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost-node-address/check",
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            $cookie
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        return "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        return $response;
    }
}
```